# Determine number of unique values of one column for each value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], "B": [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4], "C": [1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2] })

    A   B   C
0   1   1   1
1   2   1   1
2   3   2   1
3   4   2   1
4   5   3   2
5   6   3   3
6   7   4   2
7   8   4   2
```

I would like to know, for each value b of column B, how many unique values c of column C there that are in rows where B=b.

So I'd like a series that tells me something like `{1:1, 2:2, 3:2, 4:1}` meaning that, for example, when B=3, there are two unique values of C (namely 2 and 3).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby("B")["C"].nunique()

> B
  1    1
  2    1
  3    2
  4    1
  Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby("B")["C"].nunique().to_dict()
```

output:

```
{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1}
```

how does it work?

1. every time you want to calculate something in one column based on values in another, `groupby` is coming... so use it and pass all values grouped.
2. what do you want? number of unique values in `C`... so use `["C"].nunique()` that return number of unique values.
3. and at last, you want `dict`, so convert your result `to_dict()`